# k8s Service annotations for AWS NLB ALPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, nlb, alpn

I'm facing an issue on the Service annotation that enables ALPN policy in an AWS load balancer.
I'm testing an application in production, managed by EKS. I need to enable a Network Load Balancer (NLB) on AWS to manage some ingress rules (tls cert and so on...).
Among annotations is available:

`service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-alpn-policy: HTTP2Preferred`

I think I need this to enable [ALPN in the TLS handshake](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/create-tls-listener.html#:%7E:text=ssl-policies%20command.-,ALPN%20policies,-Application-Layer%20Protocol).

The issue is that it does not apply to my load balancer (other annotations works), I can confirm it by accessing the AWS dashboard or by executing `curl -s -vv https://my.example.com`. To enable this ALPN policy I must apply this patch manually, e.g. through the dashboard.

What am I missing? I wonder if that annotation could only be available for [the load balancer controller](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/service/annotations/) and not for the base [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) for NLBs.

EDIT: I found some github issues that requested for this feature in the legacy mode without using a third party controller, [here is a comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/114111#issuecomment-1360973678) that resumes all. Since it seems to be an unavailable feature (for now), how can I achieve the configuration result using terraform for example? Do I need to create the NLB first and then attach to my Service?